# Overriding the deleter of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have the following code in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class MyType{
public:
    ~MyType() {
    std::cout<<"Destructor called";
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct deleter
{
    deleter(void)  {}

    template<typename U>
    deleter(deleter<U> const&, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U*, T*>::value>* = nullptr) {}

    virtual void operator()(T* p) const 
    {
        std::cout<<"deleter called";
        static_assert(sizeof(T) > 0, "");
        if (p)
        {
            p->~T();
            free(const_cast<std::remove_const_t<T>*>(p));
        }
    }
};


template<typename T>
struct null_deleter : public deleter<T> {
    void operator()(T* ptr) const override {
        // Do nothing
        std::cout<<"null deleter called";
    }
};


template<typename T>
using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, deleter<T>>;
 
int main()
{
    MyType myType;
    std::cout<<"hello";

    unique_ptr<MyType> u(&myType);
    //unique_ptr<MyType> u(&myType, null_deleter<MyType>());
    u.get_deleter() = null_deleter<MyType>();
    return 0;
}
```

I have the requirement where I need to override the behaviour of `unique_ptr` declared as `using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, deleter<T>>;` to do nothing. So, I extended `deleter` and overrode the `operator()` . But I am getting below error in my program:

```
Program returned: 139
Program stderr
free(): invalid pointer
```

Why the program still calls `deleter<T>` instead of `null_deleter<T>`. Is there any way to override the behaviour of unique_ptr's deleter?

Comment: Did you get this deleter template from above with a condition that you use it unchanged?

Comment: Actually, I can change definition of deleter template but It is used at many places at client. So, I need to modify/extend it in such a way that it doesn't break existing clients(which use deleter<T> implementation).

Comment: This code is totally broken and has to be rewritten. If it's used in production, your clients should get their money back.

Comment: I am sorry but what's wrong with the deleter?

Comment: Just about everything. Destructor+`free` is generally behaviour, anything virtual is useless, and the deleter as a whole serves no purpose except bloating the size of the pointer with the useless vtable pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because of [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/430766). What you do when you assign to [`get_deleter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get_deleter) is copy the `deleter<T>` portion of your object:

```
Deleter& get_deleter() noexcept;
```

The carried deleter will always be of static and dynamic type `deleter<T>`. *Never*, of `null_deleter<T>` if your have an `std::unique_ptr<T, delter<T>>`.

You cannot change that afterwards.